# IBM Watson workspace orchestration

Tags: watson-assistant

I am trying to create a design for the bot, across various domains and entitlements, by using multiple workspaces.

I was thinking of an approach where there is a master workspace and multiple app workspaces, where the first input is sent to the master, and the master defines which workspace to go to. Subsequently the conversations can be sent to both master and the currently identified workspaces to dynamically route conversations between app workspaces if a switch is needed.

Is this a good design, or what is the usual design pattern for multiple workspaces, where a user can ask a generic question or a domain specific question and get an answer by switching through the workspaces?